# Window 7 High Contrast = Invisible Text/Graphics - Desktop & Websites

Tags: windows-7, themes

When any High Contrast Theme is used in Windows 7 there are items both on the desktop, various programs, and especially on websites - (using Chrome, Firefox or Explorer browsers). I have altered colors in the Personalization settings and have not found any way to make these invisible graphics and text show up. The only solution I have found is to turn off the high contrast, which makes it nearly impossible for me to see the screen, especially difficult when filling out forms.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox

1. Go to **Options** > **Content** (about:preferences#content)
2. Under "**Fonts and Color**" hit the button "**Colors...**".
3. In the "**Colors**" popup find the label "Override the colors specified by the page with my selections above:"
4. Select the list item "Never"

[image: helpful screenshot]

Comment: Here is the Chrome feature request I created for improving this situation: https://crbug.com/1231644 Please star it and add your use case in the comments. It'll help the developers justify working on this.